# When to use or not shortcut variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the best practice between these two code ?

1 - Using variables to hide the complexity and avoid repeating many time the full context

```
class FooController {
  myFunction(request, resolve, reject) {
    const lang = this.context.lang;
    const FooService = request.context.services.FooService;

    // use the variable lang multiple times (2 times to 10 times)
    FooService.getFoo().then(data => {
      data[lang] = "foo";
      resolve(data[lang]);
    }.catch(reject);
  }
}
```

2 - Repeat many time the full context of a variables

```
class FooController {
  myFunction(request, resolve, reject) {
    request.context.services.FooService.getFoo().then(data => {
      data[this.context.lang] = "foo";
      resolve(data[this.context.lang]);
    }.catch(reject);
  }
}
```

Comment: Readability is the primary objective. When you feel it makes the code easier to read, do it.

Comment: I don't think that there is an established best practice for this. Personally I'd assign the shortcut if it is used in at least 2-3 places, and use the longer form otherwise.

Comment: Seems pretty opinion based to me.

Comment: @csm_dev I disagree;)